# Get asset into a sound buffer

Tags: ios, swift, buffer, avfoundation, assets

[image]

I'm playing around with [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/HelloMetronome/Introduction/Intro.html) code example.

What I am trying to do is create a 100% Swift iOS version of this metronome app that allows playing of the MoreCowbell.caf file similar to how they have already done in the macOS example.

It makes logical sense that IF there were some way to reference this *MoreCowbell.caf* "asset"/"resource" (?) using the URL format, then the above code could work.

Is there a way to do that?  If not, then how can we refer to *MoreCowbell.caf* from code in order get those ones and zeros into the sound buffer?

I have done much googling and looking at apple documentation but and going in circles so thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a URL to files in your Bundle (ie. in your App) by using a method on `Bundle` (or `NSBundle` when using Objective-C). It works like this:

```
let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "MoreCowbell", withExtension: "caf")
```

You can find more information on this in the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle/1411540-url).

Also make sure that the file `MoreCowbell.caf` is included in your Bundle. You do that by setting it's **Target Membership**

[image: Setting Target Membership]

Comment: appreciate your answer!